# Highcharts - top justify instead of center entire chart

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I know this can be done in d3 Sankey but I don't need anything that complex. I have my Highcharts sankey complete and all my formatting is done, save one thing.

The chart renders aligned along the centerline. I'd like to set it so that the entire sankey diagram is flat against the top border of the frame.

The first node will be flat against the top, and all other nodes and links will flow down from that point. I've searched here and on the Highcharts support sites, read the APIs, and consulted The Google but I have not turned up anything.

Since this is purely aesthetic it's not a showstopper if I can't do it but since I've now seen it done in d3, I'm hoping there is a Highcharts equivalent.

Thank you

See diagram for reference (ignore colors and link weights of course)[see illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMSmq.png)
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `marginTop: 0` (see: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/p7an7h65/) or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: hi @ewolden - thank you. I'm looking for the top line from Brazil -> Portugal -> Angola -> China to be a straight horizontal line - no bends, then have the diagram expand down and fan out. I only have one starting node as well. I don't know if that clarifies. I'm trying to find an example, other than the one I have (which has sensitive information so I can't post here as an example).

Comment: @ewolden - done - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've slightly edited the core code and achieved the desired result.

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dzdsjwbs/

I've overwritten `Highcharts.seriesTypes.sankey.prototype.translate` function and commented out two lines in these two code fragments:

**1.**

```
                fromNodeTop = (
                    //column.top(factor) +
                    column.offset(node, factor)
                ),
```

**2.**

```
        toY = (
          //toColTop + 
          (toNode.offset(point, 'linksTo') * factor) +
          nodeColumns[toNode.column].offset(
            toNode,
            factor
          )
        ),
```